# C++ double ptr to long ptr conversion

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the below code fragment:

```
double * p = new double[16];

int value = 1;
void * q = p;
*((double *)q) = value;

int x = ((long *)p)[0];

cout << "Value of x for double * to long * = " << x << endl;

*((int *)q) = value  ;

x = ((long *)p)[0];

cout << "Value of x for int * to long * = " << x << endl;
```

Here the outputs are 0 and 1 respectively. Can anyone explain to me why?

Also if I directly access the value at pointer...ie.  p[0], the value is correctly shown as 1 in both case. Why?

Comment: All these typecasting are considered code smell. Do not use in real code.

Comment: This is basically a `reinterpret_cast`. The standard gives no guarantee about what result you'll get even at best (i.e., from ones that are valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers are stored in memory in straight binary so you can convert between `int`and `long` with no problem. `doulbe` is stored using the floating point binary syntax where some of the bits are used to describe the mantissa and the others are used to describe the exponent (similar to scientific notation i.e. 5e2 = 500).

If you try and use the data for a double as the data for a double then it will not convert correctly due to the different ways that the binary stores the value.